# Generically calling an overloaded method

Tags: c#

`CreateInputParameter` is an overloaded function with 6 type overloads,

is it possible to simplify the following code or is this as good as it gets?
I wish to call it like this : `CreateInputParameter( string , object )` like following code :

```
private void AddInputParameter(string description, object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();

        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            CreateInputParameter(description, (int)(value));
            return;
        }

        if (type == typeof(decimal))
        {
            CreateInputParameter(description, (decimal)(value));
            return;
        }

        if (type == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            CreateInputParameter(description, (DateTime?)(value));
            return;
        }

        if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            CreateInputParameter(description, (bool)(value));
            return;
        }

        if (type == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            CreateInputParameter(description, (byte[])(value));
            return;
        }

        if (type == typeof(Guid))
        {
            CreateInputParameter(description, (Guid)(value));
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Note that `type` will never be equal to `typeof(DateTime?)`.  Boxed nullables are boxed as the underlying type when they have a value, or as a null reference when they don't.  You should therefore test for `typeof(DateTime)` instead. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx.  (This also points out that if the value parameter is null, your method will throw.)

Comment: This question was [mentioned on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/what-more-can-i-do-for-my-question-to-not-be-off-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance:

- `Value` shouldn't be capitalized, since it's a parameter.
- The parameter is called `description`, yet your code uses `Description`.
- Why does each `if` contain a `return;`? Why not simply do `else if`? Also, can an `object` even be two different types at once?

Is this really *actual, working code*?

Also, you're not showing us `CreateInputParameter`; I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't need to be an "overloaded function with 6 type overloads". I also would expect a method called "Create" to return something, but that's open for debate.

You could look into [System.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) and use that to convert the object to a value, but again: this depends on `CreateInputParameter`. I'd advise you to submit a new question and include those methods, and provide us with more background.

Comment: I simplified this from working code, otherwise Value is a property of another object, and so was the Description. Tried to show the meat of the problem and didnt cared about code formatting as Resharper is my shepherded and I fear no code formatting evil! Thank you  :) Wether an object can be at least 2 different types at once, that is damn good question and all my code massaging seems to be pointless :( Thanks again, with those hints I think this question is now stupid and should have used a better design for this case rather than tried to jimmy bar it with ugly if's! :)

Comment: @BCdotWEB you might be interested in this [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5428/41243).